# What does it mean by "second += arr[i][arr.length-i-1]"

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I been practicing my algorithm solving skill by solving HackerRank problems. However, one of the problems is giving me a difficult time to understand. It is about calculating absolute difference between sum of diagonals in a square matrix "arr".

If the square matrix is like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
5 2 4
```

and the solution is like this:

```
1st diagonal = 1 + 5 + 4 =  10
2nd diagonal = 3 + 5 + 5 = 13
difference = |10 - 13| = 3 <-- This should appear!
```

So, I came up with this solution:

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
    let first = 0;
    let second = 0;
    let diff = 0;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       first += arr[i][i];
       second += arr[i][arr.length-i-1]
    }
    diff = first - second;
    return Math.abs(diff);
}
```

However, I figure out all other parts except the "second += arr[i][arr.length-i-1]" part.
I don't understand what [arr.length-i-1] is doing. Help me understand this.

Comment: arr.length - i - 1 => Number of rows - current position in the loop - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i` starts at 0, `arr.length - i - 1` starts at the last index in the array and iterates backwards towards the beginning. So, for example, if there are 4 elements, it'll access index `[3]`, then `[2]`, then `[1]`, then `[0]`.

For this problem, the array of arrays is square. `arr[i][arr.length - i - 1]` will result in `arr[0][2]`, then `arr[1][1]`, then `arr[2][0]` - which is the diagonal from the top right to the bottom left (which the problem is asking you to calculate).

If there were 5 subarrays, the indicies iterated over would be `arr[0][4]`, `arr[1][3]`, `arr[2][2]`, `arr[3][1]`, `arr[4][0]`. And so on.